# How to change the axis and label sizes in cdplot?

Tags: r, plot

How can I change the axis and label sizes in a `cdplot` graph? The usual `cex.lab` and `cex.axis` argument throw errors.

Comment: Cant see an argument (doesn’t mean there isnt one) so you could change the `cex` parameter before plotting ie `par(cex=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggested, you need to use

```
par(cex=2)
```

Or with a bit more targetting, use `cex.lab`, `cex.axis`, `cex.main`, or `cex.sub` to alter specific text.

Further investigating into the function, shows that the `...` argument is passed to the `stats::density` function (examine `getS3method("cdplot", "default")`)